# Swift 2、NSDictionary から値を取り出す

Tags: ios, swift

現在、Google Sheets API を使って、Google スプレッドシートの情報を JSON で取得し、その結果をパースして TableView に一覧表示するようなものを作ろうとしています。

現在書いている Swift 2 のコードはこちらです。

```
let makeStatusUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1BCAOfRDmoFLyV-bcvjFQZ2St-qg7wAUQa7o_9cn-oL8/od6/public/basic?alt=json"
let statusUrl = NSURL(string: makeStatusUrl)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(statusUrl!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
do {
    let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    var feed = dict["feed"] as! NSDictionary
    var entry = feed["entry"] as! NSArray

    for content in entry {
        let content = content["content"] as! NSDictionary
        print(content)
    }
} catch {
}})
task.resume()
```

上記のコードだと、

```
print(content)
```

の部分で次の結果が吐き出されます。

```
{
"$t" = "name: iOS, index: 12";
type = text;
}
{
"$t" = "name: Android, index: -11";
type = text;
}
{
"$t" = "name: LINE, index: 20";
type = text;
}
```

ここからが本題なのですが、上記出力結果の name と index の値をセットで取り出し、TableView に一覧表示させたいと思っています。

具体的には次のような感じです。画像では1行セットしていますが、この「iOS 12」の下に同じ形式で「Android -11」、「LINE 20」と続いていく感じです。
[image]

自分としては name と index を NSDictionary でセットし、それを表示するようにコードを書けばよいのでは と思っていますが、初心者のためどのように書いたらよいか分かりません。

ご教授願います。

また、スタック・オーバーフロー も初心者ですので、不備などがありましたら回答、および編集などをしていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ひとまず回答したが本来は回答でそうしたようにフローを小分けして幾つかの質問に分割する規模だと思う。回答に沿った作業で不明な点が出てきたら整理して一つずつ新しい質問として投稿すると良い

Answer (score 4, accepted):

前提

1. テーブルビューのアウトレット接続とデリゲート設定が済んでいるものとする
2. JSONダウンロードの実行ボタンとして「Reload」（`reload`関数が実行される）ボタンがあるものとする

---

データソース

テーブルビューに表示するデータは順序が必要なため、一般的には配列を使用する
今回は`feed["entry"]`で取得できる配列をデータソースとして`var dataSource: [NSDictionary]`プロパティへ格納する

---

JSONのダウンロード

ダウンロードはバックグラウンドで行う
ダウンロードの完了通知を受け取るためビューコントローラは`NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`プロトコルを採用し`URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)`関数を実装する

---

JSONの解析

1. テーブルのデータソースとして都合のよい配列を取得する
2. 配列を`dataSource`プロパティへ格納する
3. メインスレッドでテーブルを更新する（UIの更新はメインスレッドで行う）

---

テーブルのための整形

テーブルを更新したことで`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`関数がデータソースの内容を元に実行される

ここでは配列から取り出したデータを表示に適したものへ整形しセルのラベルへセットする
例）`name: iOS, index: 12` -> `iOS`と`12`へ

---

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var dataSource: [NSDictionary]! = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func reload(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1BCAOfRDmoFLyV-bcvjFQZ2St-qg7wAUQa7o_9cn-oL8/od6/public/basic?alt=json"
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("Configuration")
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!)

    task.resume()
  }

  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    let json = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
    do {
      let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
      let feed = dict["feed"] as! NSDictionary
      self.dataSource = feed["entry"] as! [NSDictionary]

      NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
      })
    } catch {
      print("JSON parse error")
    }
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44;
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count;
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]["content"] as! NSDictionary
    let raw = content["$t"] as? String
    let values = raw?.componentsSeparatedByString(", ") as [String]!
    let name = values[0].substringFromIndex(values[0].rangeOfString(": ")!.endIndex)
    let index = values[1].substringFromIndex(values[1].rangeOfString(": ")!.endIndex)

    cell.textLabel?.text = name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = index

    return cell
  }
}
```

---

実行画面:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: わかりやすい回答、ありがとうございました。
おかげさまで期待した動作が正しく行われることを確認することが出来ました。